# SCDF. WSDL Source : Spring Cloud Task or Spring Cloud Stream or any other solution?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We have requirements for getting data from a SOAP web service, where same records are going to be exposed. Then the record is transformed and written do the DB.
We are the acitve side and at the certain intervals we are going to check if a new record has appeared.

Our main goal are:

- to have a scheduler for setting intervals
- to have a mechanizm to retry if something goes wrong (eg. lost connection)
- to have a visual control of the process - check the places where something stuck (like dashboard in SCDF)

Since there is no sample wsdl source app, I guess the Task (or Stream ?) should be written by ourself. But what to use for repeating and scheduling...

I Need your advice in choosing the right approach.

I'm not tied to the SCDF solution if any other are more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to consume directly as SOAP messages from external services, you could either build a custom Spring Cloud Stream source or a simple Spring Batch/Spring Cloud Task application. Both the options provide the resiliency patterns, including retries.

However, if the upstream data is not real-time, you would choose the Task path because the streams are long-running and they never terminate. Tasks, on the other hand, run for a finite period of time, terminate, and free-up resources. There's also the option to use the platform-specific scheduler implementation to trigger to launch the Task on a recurring window periodically.

From the SCDF dashboard, you can [design/build](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_the_lifecycle_of_a_composed_task) Composed Tasks, including the [state transitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-data-flow-transitional-execution) and the desired downstream operation.